# purpose of scala type (=> A) => O

Tags: scala

I found a strange type in [this](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/998f436e21b96b1241aab46d666cba9f8e6d7b0f/extra/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/extra/router/Dsl.scala#L417) code on github:

```
  final class StaticRouteB[Page, O](private val f: (=> Action[Page]) => O) extends AnyVal {
    def ~>(a: => Action[Page]): O = f(a)
  }
```

1. The type of `f`. What does it mean ?  My guess is that it is a function with a call by name argument. Never seen it before, so I am not sure what it is or how does this thing work.
2. Is there a way to translate this type into something more "standard" ? (The code above I mean, so that it does not use the `(=> Action[Page]) => O)` type ? Is this type just some syntactic sugar ?)
3. I wonder especially, what happens if I pass `Action[Page] => O` as `f` when creating `StaticRouteB` ? Will I get a compile error ? Run time error ? Why ? I mean, what is the purpose of `(=> ... )` ? Is it to give a compile error if not the right kind of function is passed or to change the evaluation strategy of `f`'s parameters ? I mean why would anyone want to have a type like this ? For what purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(=> Action[Page])` is a "*call by name*" parameter.

So `f: (=> Action[Page]) => O` is a function with a call by name parameter of type Action[Page], and this function returns result of type O.

You can see its usage in a method `~>` definition.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to translate this type into something more "standard" ?

Comment: Also, I wonder especially, what happens if I pass `Action[Page] => O` as `f` when creating `StaticRouteB` ? Will I get a compile error ? Run time error ?

Comment: This is the standard and simpliest way to write this type. You can use type alias if you want. But that won't simplify anything "under hood".

Comment: If you try to pass a function with type `Action[Page] => O` to this constructor, you will get a compile error, as it's different type. You can always try it with simplified example.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you for the clarification.